# After clicking on the “back” button, Chrome and Edge forgets dynamic changes in HTML blocks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Simple test code:

```
<html>
<script>
    function changeAnchor()
    {
        document.getElementById('link').innerText = 'Second anchor';
        return false;
    }
</script>
<body>

<a href="" id="link" onClick="return changeAnchor();">First anchor</a><br>
<a href="https://google.com">Google</a>

</body>
</html>
```

If in Google Chrome or Edge I click on "First anchor", it changes to "Second Anchor". If after that I click on Google link, and press "back" button in browser, Chrome and Edge shows page whith "First anchor", but not whith "Second anchor" - as it was before click on Google.

In Firefox it's OK.

How to make Chrome and Edge show the page after returning exactly as it was before  clicking on external link?

Comment: Firefox may be caching the changed DOM, so the Back button loads the latest DOM, not the original page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that the above code works as expected in the Firefox browser. I tested it in the Firefox browser but it also shows similar results as Edge and Chrome browser. Not sure, how it works on your side.

**Below is the test result with the Firefox browser:**

[image]

If we talk about your question,**How to make Chrome and Edge show the page after returning exactly as it was before clicking on external link?**

I suggest you use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and set its value after setting the inner text for the link. At starting of the script, you can fetch the value from local storage and set the inner text.

Modified example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="" id="link" onClick="return changeAnchor();">First anchor</a><br>
    <a href="http://localhost">Localhost</a><br>
    <button id="btn1" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

    <script>
        var link_text = "";
        if (localStorage.getItem("lnk_txt") !== "")
        {
            document.getElementById('link').innerText = localStorage.getItem("lnk_txt");
        }
        function changeAnchor()
        {
            document.getElementById('link').innerText = 'Second anchor';
            link_text="Second anchor";
            localStorage.setItem("lnk_txt", link_text);
            return false;
        }
        function reset()
        {
            document.getElementById('link').innerText = 'First anchor';
            localStorage.setItem("lnk_txt", "");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output in the Edge browser:**

[image]

**This solution will work with all major browsers.**

Comment: Thanks! It works, but with little correction - not                                                                   if (localStorage.getItem("lnk_txt") !== "")                                                                        but                                                                                                                             if (localStorage.getItem("lnk_txt") !== null)

Comment: If you think the suggestion can help you to fix the issue then please accept the helpful suggestion as an answer to this question. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks for your understanding.